# SSH to my Ubuntu Server Machine from Outside Home Network

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I have setup OpenSSH correctly on my ubuntu server 16.0.4, so it is letting me connect from my home network. But, I would like to be able to connect to it from outside my home network.

I know that in order for this to happen I need to forward a port and some other stuff, but I can not figure out that other stuff.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Port forwarding is more a function of your router than something about Ubuntu. What is your model of router, and is it running anything besides the default firmware? Portforward.net is a pretty comprehensive resource for finding how to do a port forward  no matter what router you are using.

Comment: You only need to open port 22 on your router. You don't need to do anything on Ubuntu.

Comment: You may also need a dynamic DNS (DDNS) assuming your Internet provide does not give your home a static IP.

Comment: "Just opening port 22  is a *really* bad idea!  @Jo-ErlendSchinstad

Comment: @Fabby: Why is that a bad idea?

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad http://bfy.tw/Djd0

Comment: @Fabby: Well, ssh is one of the most secure services we have. If we cannot use ssh on the internet, Linux should not be used to host internet services at all.

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad I never said you shouldn't use SSH  I said don't use port 22.

Comment: @Fabby: That's nonsensical. It makes absolutely no difference to an attacker which port number you use. It's just confusing for your legitimate users.